# PHP crypt() function very slow

Tags: codeigniter, hash, authentication, bcrypt, ion-auth

I am using bcrypt for password encryption during the login process. The php crypt() function is taking over 25 seconds to complete. Is there any good reason it would take this long?

Comment: Post your code here. Have you set `cost` option different than default?

Comment: this line is taking 27 seconds to complete: $hash = crypt($input, $existingHash);

Comment: You are right - it is not good. [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) are more recommended functions. Have you tried those?